# How to overcome cold start issue in AWS Lambda with Zappa?

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, zappa, cold-start

I have deployed api (Django application) in AWS using zappa. I'm facing cold start issue. It is taking nearly 7-8 sec to start application (code is nearly 25 MB ).How to overcome this issue ??

In zappa settings.json , i have kept **keep_warm=true** but of no use.
I have written lambda function to trigger api using scheduling cloudwatch event , it is triggering ( i can see in zappa logs ) but problem not solved.

sample code of my handler is :

```
import json
def lambda_handler(event, context):
# TODO implement
return {
    'statusCode': 200,
    'body': json.dumps('Hello from Lambda!')
}
```

My zappa configurations are :

```
{
    "dev": {
        "aws_region": "ap-south-1",
        "django_settings": "api.settings",
        "profile_name": "default",
        "project_name": "api-public",
        "runtime": "python3.6",
        "s3_bucket": "api-public",
        "slim_handler": true,
        "vpc_config" : {
            "SubnetIds": [ "subnet-052347e86b94b75d3" ], // use the private subnet
            "SecurityGroupIds": [ "sg-0ba3a644d413a2b00","sg-0db0b6de5b14cda33"]
        },
        "xray_tracing": true,// Optional, enable AWS X-Ray tracing on your lambda function.
        "memory_size": 1024, // Lambda function memory in MB. Default 512.
        "log_level": "DEBUG", // Set the Zappa log level. Can be one of CRITICAL, ERROR, WARNING, INFO and DEBUG. Default: DEBUG
        "keep_warm": true, // Create CloudWatch events to keep the server warm. Default true. To remove, set to false and then `unschedule`.
        "timeout_seconds": 300,
        "keep_warm_expression": "rate(3 minutes)", // How often to execute the keep-warm, in cron and rate format. Default 4 minutes.
        "exclude": [
            ".git/*",
            ".gitignore",
            "boto3*",
            "*botocore*",
            "django-debug-toolbar*",
            "sqlparse*",
            "zappa_settings.json",
            "README.md"
        ],
        "lambda_description": "zappa deployment public", // However you want to describe your project for the AWS console. Default "Zappa Deployment".
        "extra_permissions": [{ // Attach any extra permissions to this policy. Default None
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "lambda:InvokeFunction", 
            "Resource": ["arn:aws:lambda:ap-east-1:940180048916:function:api-public-dev"],// AWS Service ARN
        }],
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that AWS changed how Lambda networking happens to reduce the impact of these cold starts. Not fully rolled out yet, but on its way. For more, read https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/announcing-improved-vpc-networking-for-aws-lambda-functions/

Answer (score 3):

If you need to keep warm a Django application, you're using AWS Lambda functions the wrong way, for start. (trust me, personal experience)

AWS Lambda functions were created to deploy lightweight functions to the world. Your Django app is a heavy(iest) function ever.

AWS Lambda was designed for apps that have lifetime of fractions of second. 25 MB for itself is a huge load to Lambda functions.

Consider using a lightweight framework as Flask, instead. Don't overcome Lambda functions. They were not meant for that.

Use AWS ECS, instead.

Answer (score 0):

Can you include your Zappa configuration? Here's an example of how `keep_warm` should be used, in the context of the settings file, with more settings included:

```
{
    "production": {
        "aws_region": "us-east-1",
        "django_settings": "config.zappa",
        "profile_name": "zappa",
        "project_name": "mydomain",
        "runtime": "python3.6",
        "s3_bucket": "zappa-mydomain",
        "certificate_arn": "arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:272727272727:certificate/eeeeeeee-dddd-cccc-bbbb-aaaaaaaaaaaa",
        "domain": "mydomain.com",
        "exclude": [
                ".git/*",
                ".gitignore",
            "boto3*",
            "*botocore*",
            "django-debug-toolbar*",
            "sqlparse*",
            "zappa_settings.json",
            "README.md"
        ],
        "keep_warm": true,
        "timeout_seconds": 300
    }
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: as per ur suggestion, i kept the above settings ...code size decreased by 5Mb but no luck with cold start issue

Comment: i have added my zappa configuration (Edited).

Comment: When you deploy, do you see a line during deployment that says it is setting up keep warm? When I deploy, mine says this.

Comment: when i see logs i found this :  [1555906810631] [DEBUG] 2019-04-22T04:20:10.629Z aef9d3a6-57f6-436a-956e-c0713c909b47 Zappa Event: {'time': '2019-04-22T04:19:24Z', 'detail-type': 'Scheduled Event', 'source': 'aws.events', 'account': '940180048916', 'region': 'ap-east-1', 'detail': {}, 'version': '0', 'resources': ['arn:aws:events:ap-south-1:940183248916:rule/2f22u81036ca6tre8a11f0671216dbc14c4e4-handler.keep_warm_callback'], 'id': '620e9999-95cb-7116-9061-b4e000239fed', 'kwargs': {}}         but its not working

Comment: is there anything to do with region mentioned in zappa settings.json??

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not sure. There is a Slack for Zappa that might be worth asking on: https://slack.zappa.io/

Answer (score 0):

Technically, this is not an issue if we can accept the fact that this is one of the AWS lambda function limitation.

The main issue here is that, we are forcing ourselves to use lambda which is obviously  not fit to the requirements due to that limitation (delay).

The problem if we use lambda for this case is this,

- keeping lambda function alive for certain time would be expensive! super expensive and obviously lambda(container) is not design to work like that dude!

Instead of by passing  the way lambda normally works and cost you a lot of money, I would like to suggest to use an EC2 as your web serer (API) with auto scaling and load balancing on top of it.

In this approach the response back from the API 
- will be way faster, because your api is awake and waiting for any request
- more cheaper than you having it on lambda, because lambda charged $0.00001667 per GB-second of compute time your Lambda performs, imagine your lambda awake for 10 mins :)

Hope this helps! :)

Cheers! 
Monkeys

Comment: Your answer is fundamentally wrong! Keeping a Lambda alive doesn't mean you are executing code for a X amount of time, but just pinging the container every once in a while instead. Containers, usually, live for about 5 minutes if they are idle (there are articles stating that sometimes it can live up to 45 minutes). Furthermore, you say Lambda is pricy but then you mention EC2 with auto-scaling and ELB, which will be way more expensive than Lambda for low traffic (by low I am talking about 30 million executions per month). If these functions run for one second and are configured(cont...)

Comment: to use 1024MB, it would only cost 49 USD a month. If you then configure 2 medium EC2 instances at least for your auto-scaling groups with one ELB on top this would already cost 53 USD, which makes it 10% more expensive already. This would go way higher with traffic spikes though. Long story short: if you don't know the traffic and if you don't know how Lambda cold starts work, you should not be giving false assumptions.

Comment: Not to mention that functions usually run faster than a second (but let's keep it for simplicity) and most of the times 1024MB per function is overkill. If we drop this number to 256MB (more than enough in most cases), then the cost for the Lambda functions would only be 11 USD per month.

Comment: So now, how do you warm that aws lambda function without trigger your function???

Also, if you dont have calculator use one with AWS. see attached screen cap 

[enter image description here][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/18P2R.png

Comment: dude to help for that computation:

based from you:

1. Number of Executions = 30,000,000
2. Allocated Memory (MB) = 1024MB
3. Estimated Execution Time (ms) = 5000 (5secs)

will cost you per month = $2499.63/month

math matters :) peace

Comment: 0 - Yes, I used a calculator. 1 - You only pay for when the code RUNS, but a container stays alive sometime after that and you DON'T pay if there's no code being executed. 2 - I clearly said 1 second per execution. 3 - I also clearly said that most of the times the memory can be reduced, so I reduced it to 256MB. 4 - That would cost only 11 USD a month. 5 - This is too much for your peanut brain to process.

Comment: AWS Lambda functions were not created for heavy loads indeed. Django application is the heaviest load ever.

Answer (score 0):

The periodic hits is simple techniques, yet it would not help with the case of simultaneous requests. One lamdba instance can handle only one request at time. I am not sure how exactly to do it with zappa. Yet the promising solution is using docker checkpoints

https://www.imperial.ac.uk/media/imperial-college/faculty-of-engineering/computing/public/1819-ug-projects/StenbomO-Refunction-Eliminating-Serverless-Cold-Starts-Through-Container-Reuse.pdf

Of course ou can double memory. It would not double to bill because requests would be processed faster.

I also a bit fantasized of adding to zappa fancy strategies like running cheep 1M instances by default but detect cold start and redirect to 3M instances or beans, but checkpoints seems more promising for oversized frameworks like django.